# Level based view color in Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I have numbers between 1 - 100. And every number has to change view's color.

What should I use? I think about using canvas but my image is like this:

[image]

If I use canvas, I have to know RGB algorithm for this image, don't I? It goes green to red.

I've stucked about this topic, what should I do? What do you recommend?

My Canvas class is;

```
public class CircleCanvasView extends View {

Paint paint;
Path path;
int level = 0;

public CircleCanvasView(Context context, int level) {
    super(context);
    init();
    this.level = level;
}

public CircleCanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CircleCanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I use canvas, I have to know RGB algorithm for this image, don't I?
>   It goes green to red.

Not really. What you need is an interpolator for your color. And you want to change the colors in-between in 100 steps. You have your startColor and your endColor, two int values. Through the color class you can get their single components:

```
int alpha = Color.alpha(startColor);
int red = Color.red(startColor);
int blue = Color.blue(startColor);
int green = Color.green(startColor);
```

and

```
int endalpha = Color.alpha(endColor);
int endred = Color.red(endColor);
int endblue = Color.blue(endColor);
int endgreen = Color.green(endColor);
```

and you want something like

```
   int cAlpha = alpha + factor * (endAlpha - alpha);
   int cRed = red + factor * (endAlpha - red);
   int cBlue = blue + factor * (endAlpha - blue);
   int cGreen = green + factor * (endAlpha - green);
```

with `0 <= factor <= 1`

when factor is 0 you have the start components, when factor is 1 yo`enter code here`u have the end componets. To get the color at each step:

```
 int colorAtStep = Color.argb(cAlpha, cRed, cBlue, cGreen);
```

Comment: or just use ArgbEvaluator

Comment: @pskink, thanks, I never heard of.. I quickly looked it up, and it is available from api 11

Comment: oh come in, dont be a caveman,  who uses api 11? fred flinston and his family?  :-)

Comment: @pskink we still maintain backwards compatibility with gingerbread. It is still 9% of the devices on the market

Comment: @pskink I still support API Level **8**.

Comment: @Blackbelt i believe that those 9% are from the countries (you know what i mean) where you have almost no customers,  but i may be wrong...

Comment: @pskink, unfortunately 13% of our users are still on gb

Comment: I've edited question, I've added my canvas class, how can I use your code or ArgbEvaluator?